# Issue with installation of powercli in docker

Tags: php, docker, powershell, dockerfile, powercli

I have installed PowerShell on php docker image and now trying to install VMWare PowerCLI
I am getting the following error on line 44

```
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP  -Confirm:
     |                                                                     ~
     | Parameter -Confirm: requires an argument.

ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false -Confirm:$false"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**Line 44:** `RUN pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false -Confirm:$false"`

This is my docker file

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    wget \
    apt-utils

# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

# Start PowerShell
#RUN pwsh

#Install VMWare PowerCLI
RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Scope CurrentUser"
RUN pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP $false -Confirm:$false"
RUN pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore"

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I could not figure how to resolve. Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**
To remove the previous error I used 0 instead of $false
The modified the dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    wget \
    apt-utils

# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
RUN dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Update the list of products
RUN apt-get update

# Install PowerShell
RUN apt-get install -y powershell

# Start PowerShell
#RUN pwsh

#Install VMWare PowerCLI
RUN pwsh -c "Save-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Path ~/"
RUN pwsh -c "Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Scope CurrentUser -Force"
RUN pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -ParticipateInCEIP 0 -Confirm:0"
RUN pwsh -c "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope User -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:0"
RUN pwsh -c "Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.PowerCLI"
RUN pwsh -c "Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI"
```

Now the error is as follows:

```
Exception: VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView module is not currently supported on the Core edition of PowerShell.
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pwsh -c "Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Try to disable module:
https://cloudhat.eu/powercli-10-0-0-linux-error-vmware-vimautomation-srm/

Comment: Yes. I have seen the post. I am using docker. So the changes will be lost when I restart the container. Is there a way I can do it in dockerfile?

Comment: Configure it in the Dockerfile (in image), not in the container

Comment: I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: ```RUN pwsh -c Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI -ErrorAction Continue``` also fails

Comment: If I skip the line ```RUN pwsh -c 'Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI``` build is successful. But the commands are  not found. I feel this is because the module is not loaded. Is there a work around how I can import the modules?

Comment: You can edit files during the build for disabling modules, i.e. `sed -i 's/@{"ModuleName"="VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView"/#@{"ModuleName"="VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView"/g' path/to/file`

Comment: Thanks. Instead of installing PowerCLI as a whole I installed only required modules as ```RUN Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Import-Module```. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems without VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView and others' dependencies entire PowerCLI modules cannot be installed.

So, Instead of installing the entire PowerCLI and its dependant modules as a whole, I installed only required modules as:

`RUN pwsh -Command Get-Module -ListAvailable VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Import-Module`.

Alternatively, you can also use below to only import the modules you need. Thanks to [Scepticalist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6203113/scepticalist):

`RUN pwsh -Command 'Import-Module -Name VMware.VimAutomation.Core -Scope CurrentUser'`

This solves the issue.